# Can I use @Html.TextBoxFor another class (no model)?

Tags: c#, forms, razor

I have a Razor's view that contains a model and a filters form (to search), also I defined a class searchStruct.cs :

```
public class searchStruct
{
    public string SearchPattern { get; set; }
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

and I like to use the TextBoxFor Helper and use it with searchStruct instead of model. It's posible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should simply update your main view model so that it contains a property of this type:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public searchStruct SearchStruct { get; set; }

    ... // some other properties of your view model
}
```

and then in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchStruct.SearchPattern)
```

So basically this answer is saying that you should be using a view model instead of passing your domain entities to the view.

Comment: But what happen when there is another "model"?

Comment: There can't be another model in an MVC view other than a **view model**. If you have another model then you are doing it wrong and you should substitute this model (I guess domain model coming from EF) with a view model and let the controller do the mapping logic between the two. But at the end of the day, your view should be strongly typed to a view model over which you have full control. Think of the view model as a projection of one or more domain models to the specific needs of a particular view.